# Unable to validate just a single property with Blazored Fluent Validation

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, fluentvalidation

In a vanilla .NET 6 Blazor Server project, I am using [Blazored.FluentValidation](https://github.com/Blazored/FluentValidation) 2.1.0. When trying to validate a single property, as documented in the [FluentValidation docs](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/specific-properties.html), it is triggering the validation for the whole form.

I've tried to create a .NET 6 MVC project and used [FluentValidation](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation) 11.5.2 directly. As expected, only the provided property is being validated when I call `Validate()` by specifying the property in the `IncludeProperties()` method. Is there something wrong that I'm doing or missing from my side on Blazor Server?

Reproduction steps:

1. Create a `FormModel.cs` class

```cs
public class FormModel
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public string? Comment { get; set; }
}
```

2. Create a `FormModelValidator.cs` class

```cs
public class FormModelValidator : AbstractValidator<FormModel>
{
    public FormModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Name is mandatory");
        RuleFor(x => x.Email).NotEmpty().EmailAddress().WithMessage("Email is mandatory and must be valid");
        RuleFor(x => x.Comment).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Comment is mandatory");
    }
}
```

3. Register validation class in `Program.cs`

```cs
builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<FormModelValidator>();
```

4. Create form in a Razor page

```cs
<EditForm Model="@_model">
    <FluentValidationValidator @ref="_fluentValidationValidator" DisableAssemblyScanning="@true" />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <InputText id="name" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@_model.Name" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => _model.Name)" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <InputText id="email" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@_model.Email" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => _model.Email)" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
        <InputTextArea id="comment" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@_model.Comment" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => _model.Comment)" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@HandleSubmit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@if (_formSubmitted)
{
    <p class="text-success">Form submitted successfully!</p>
}

@if (_formError)
{
    <p class="text-danger">Form is incorrect!</p>
}

@code {
    private FormModel _model = new FormModel();
    private bool _formSubmitted, _formError;
    private FluentValidationValidator? _fluentValidationValidator;

    private async Task HandleSubmit()
    {
        var isValid = await _fluentValidationValidator!.ValidateAsync(options => options.IncludeProperties("Comment"));
        if (isValid)
        {
            _formSubmitted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            _formError = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See following : https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/start.html

Comment: Can you try `ValidateAsync(_model, options => options.IncludeProperties(x => x.Comment))`

Comment: @MathewThompson It seems that the Blazored.FluentValidation does not have this method override: https://github.com/Blazored/FluentValidation/blob/v2.1.0/src/Blazored.FluentValidation/FluentValidationsValidator.cs

Comment: @chris05 Ah sorry I assumed there was an async equivalent. Here's the standard one: https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/specific-properties.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your problem is that with the button type as `submit`, the form is submitted and `HandleSubmitAsync` is called.

This is the `EditForm` code.

```cs
private async Task HandleSubmitAsync()
{
    Debug.Assert(_editContext != null);

    if (OnSubmit.HasDelegate)
        await OnSubmit.InvokeAsync(_editContext);

    else
    {
        var isValid = _editContext.Validate();

        if (isValid && OnValidSubmit.HasDelegate)
            await OnValidSubmit.InvokeAsync(_editContext);

        if (!isValid && OnInvalidSubmit.HasDelegate)
            await OnInvalidSubmit.InvokeAsync(_editContext);
    }
}
```

You don't have a registered `OnSubmit` delegate, so `var isValid = _editContext.Validate();` is run which validates the whole object.

There are two solutions to the problem.

1. Change the button type in this line:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@HandleSubmit">Submit</button>
```

To:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@HandleSubmit">Submit</button>
```

2. Register your `HandleSubmit` handler on the `EditForm` and remove it from the button.

```
<EditForm Model="@_model" OnSubmit="HandleSubmit">

//....

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

BTW - excellent *Minimal Reproducible Example*.

Comment: Wild. So that `HandleSubmitAsync` is just dynamically created as part of having an `EditForm`?

Comment: No, it's `EditForm` code - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c7d58cdfd4bf5d6b4a214534303510d3f1f6f0c1/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/EditForm.cs#LL189C1-L189C1.    `EditForm`'s content output writes out a standard html form and hooks up the browser native `onsubmit` event to  `HandleSubmitAsync`.

Comment: Oh, of course. Because at the end of the day an `EditForm` is just a component like everything else. I guess I never thought to actually go look at the source.